# osx mkdir can not create folders at ~

Tags: macos

I have a couple of scripts for configuring new computers. I have a section dedicated to osx, where I create specific osx stuff. I wanted to change the default location for screenshots,but first I need to create the required folder. However, when I try to create the folder at `~/Documents/screenshots` I get a variety of errors:

- If I just use mkdir, then it tells me that the file already exists
- If I add the `-p` option then I get no error, but nothing happens, the file does not get created

I tried the same code on the console directly with identical results.
Here is a small part of the code. The get boolean response is just a small function that returs true or false depending if the user types Yes or No

```
#!/bin/bash

  screenshotsFolder="~/Documents/screenshots"
  if get_boolean_response "Create a folder for the screenshots at $screenshotsFolder?"; then
     mkdir "$screenshotsFolder"
  fi
```

I tried changing the name to a random one, but I get exactly the same results.
Any advice?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's the same problem. However, I was not able to find that answer with my current mindset, that's why I opened an issue with a different wording that will match less technical searches. Should I close/delete it or making the solution easier to find deserves the duplication ?

Comment: use `$HOME` instead of `~`: `screenshotsFolder="$HOME/Documents/screenshots"`